# Почему не отображается имя python приложения в мониторе sql management studio?

Tags: python, sql-server

С помощью auto-py-to-exe упаковал .py в exe-приложение, работающее с бд ms sql. В мониторе активности management studio подключение отображается, но имя приложения пустое. А нужно видеть какое именно приложение в данный момент выполняет запросы. Что не так с .exe и как поправить?

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1),
auto-py-to-exe 2.36.0,
Management Studio 17

Comment: Это надо задавать в настройках подключения

Comment: Спасибо! Как я сразу не догадался?) Реально,  возможность добавления параметра APP в любой pyodbc.connect(' ... ;APP=app_name_1;') даже в рамках одного приложения решила у меня сразу несколько проблем